# Horizontally fixed element, with absolute vertical position

Tags: jquery, css

I have a horizontally scrolling website with header menu ... now, at some point, the site content is long enough to show a vertical scroll bar. I have the menu fixed positioned, so scrolling to left and right works nicely ... but when scrolling down, the menu obviously goes over the content. My question is, is there a way, with jquery / CSS to let the menu be fixed when horizontally scrolling and then absolute position it to the top, when scrolling down?

Comment: Hi Martin, It's not completely clear to me what you want to archieve. Can you point out an example or add some image that clearifies?

Comment: Is there a reason you need fixed position? Also you say:  `so scrolling to left and right works nicely` Why do one want to scroll to left / right on a page? Just curious.

Comment: Of course, here's an example: http://stack.latorante.name/ (not optimized or anything, but you get the drift right?)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like the following ([example/fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/ResGM/1/)):

CSS:

```
#headerMenu {
   position: absolute;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $("#headerMenu")
      .stop(false, true)
      .animate({"marginLeft": ($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"}, "slow" );
});
```

If you don't want animation, you could use this jQuery call ([example/fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/katowulf/7Bz9g/1/)):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
   $("#headerMenu")
      .css({"margin-left": ($(window).scrollLeft()) + "px"});
});
```

Also, here is a real-world example scrolling vertically which hides content under the header area: http://www.havenshade.com/experience.php

Comment: Glad to help; you could give it a plus one if you're happy with it :)