# horizontally fixed position for element in React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an icon element in a ListItem component. This listItem component belongs a larger component (FiltersPanel component) which has scroll in it. Both horizontal scroll and the vertical scroll.

Hierarchy of component: ...other high level component -> FiltersPanel -> FolderFilter -> GroupNavListView -> GroupNavListItem -> CollapsibleList -> CollapsibleListItem -> MenuIconElement

Now, I want to make the MenuIconElement position to fixed horizontally but not vertically. How this can be done.

This question is similar to: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903939/horizontally-fixed-element-with-absolute-vertical-position]
But the difference lies in the usage of react component. The scroll doesn't belong to window instead it belongs only to a specific component.

Comment: so basically you want to add a scrollbar but only inside a component and not globally, so if i make a component which is in the center of the screen and only the content inside that component is scrolling will that solve your problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by " if i make a component which is in the center of the screen".

Also, my question is not making the component scrollable rather making an icon inside the component, fixed in a particular position while scrolling horizontally but making it scrollable vertically.